# Jenkins powershell ng is not recognized

Tags: node.js, jenkins, deployment, compiler-errors, web-deployment

**When I run Jenkins job**

[image]

**I get the following error:**

`the term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`

[image]

Does anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the **path** of `ng` executable to your `%PATH%` envirment variable.

If you installed `@angular/cli` globally, it should be `%AppData%\npm\bin` .

Or if you installed that only inside the project, it should be `.\node_modules\.bin` .

In Powershell, just use

```
$env:Path += ";$env:APPDATA\npm\bin"
```

Comment: sorry, It is okay for me to execute on the host, but it can not be done in jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

1. install nodejs in jenkins.
2. Global Tool Configuration in jenkins.

[image]

3. Build environment on job page.

[image]

4. powershell enter ng build, success.